# Google Compute Engine, Queue Incoming Data from Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-tasks

I am attempting to connect cloud functions with an AI program running on Compute Engine that processes incoming data. The Cloud Function currently is triggered by a change in a Cloud Storage bucket and starts the VM each time data is uploaded, but when lots of data is uploaded simultaneously, the instance is restarted several times, interrupting the data processing. How can I queue the incoming data, and have the Compute Engine instance read and process that incoming data as previous processes finish? I have looked at Pub/Sub and Cloud Tasks, but those implementations mention scaling multiple instances or connecting to App Engines. Would be process that analyzes the data need to be modified in order to handle data sequentially, or can that be done with Google Cloud tools?

**EDIT**

Attached is the cloud function that runs when a file is uploaded in the GCS bucket. Notice how the instance triggered is always the same one, and my theory is that the subsequent triggers rewrite the metadata, and either instantly restart the instance or change the instructions for the instance, and thus interrupt the processing of the previous files.

```
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def start(event, context):
    file = event
    print(file["id"])

    string = file["id"]

    newstring = string.split('/')
    userId = newstring[1]
    paymentId = newstring[2]
    name = newstring[3]

    print(name)

    if name == "uploadcomplete.txt":
        startup_script = """#! /bin/bash
                cd ~ && pwd 1>>/var/log/log.out 2>&1
                PATH=$PATH://usr/local/cuda 1>>/var/log/log.out 2>&1
                cd program_directory 1>>/var/log/log.out 2>&1
                source /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh 1>/var/log/log.out 2>&1
                conda activate env
                cd keras-retinanet/ 1>>/var/log/log.out 2>&1
                export PYTHONPATH=`pwd` 1>>/var/log/log.out 2>&1
                cd tracker 1>>/var/log/log.out 2>&1
                python program_name --gcs_input_path gs://input/{userId}/{paymentId} --gcs_output_path gs://output/{userId}/{paymentId} 1>>/var/log/log.out 2>&1
                sudo python3 gcs_to_mongo.py {userId} {paymentId} 1>>/var/log/log.out 2>&1
                sudo shutdown -P now
                """.format(userId=userId, paymentId=paymentId)
                
        service = build('compute', 'v1', cache_discovery=False)
        print('VM Instance starting')
        project = 'XXXX'
        zone = 'us-east1-c'
        instance = 'YYYY'
        metadata = service.instances().get(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
        metares = metadata.execute()
        print(metares)
    
        fingerprint = metares["metadata"]["fingerprint"]
        print(fingerprint)
        bodydata = {"fingerprint": fingerprint,
                    "items": [{"key": "startup-script", "value": startup_script}]}

        print(bodydata)        
        meta = service.instances().setMetadata(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance,
                                               body=bodydata)
        res = meta.execute()
        instanceget = service.instances().get(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance).execute()
        request = service.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
        response = request.execute()
        print('VM Instance started')
        print(instanceget)
        print("'New Metadata:", instanceget['metadata'])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the instance is restarted several times"?  Cloud Functions invocations don't get interrupted by other invocations.  Each invocations runs to completion unless the code itself decides to terminate (or crash).  Invocations run in parallel no problem, and there should be no need to serialize your work unless that is a requirement in your code.

Comment: @DougStevenson the data that was being processed would not be completely processed because the VM would be restarted. The same instance was being stopped and started again when the function triggered, and the startup script would contain different data.

Comment: What do you mean by "the VM was restarted"? How did you observe this behavior?  What you're describing doesn't sound like Cloud Functions at all.  Or are you describing Compute Engine?  It might be helpful if you show some code, error messages, or anything that helps the reader of the question see what you're seeing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I’m referring to the Compute Engine starting and stopping. The behavior that occurs is more of a reinitializing. I’m away from the computer at the moment, but the startup script that I attach to the VM instance contains a Python program that triggers another Cloud function. That Python program contains code that’s not being run, and when multiple changes are made to the storage bucket, only the most recent changes are processed by the virtual machine, the other changes are ignored. If that makes sense.

Comment: @DougStevenson edited my post with the cloud function